# How to generate reports for each class using ITestListener?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extent

Just a single HTML Report is generated with all of the screenshots of different classes when running the suite which are executed one after another. 
To generate the reports, I have ITestListener with Extent Report 3.0, TestNG 6.11, Selenium Webdriver 3.0 and Java.

My question is: Can I get different HTML reports generated for each class I execute using ITestListener?

For example: class "A" have 4 test case and class "B" have 6 test case then two HTML Report should be generated and in the 1st Report should display 4 Test Case and 2nd Report should display 6 Test case.

testng.xml:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="Listener"/> 
</listeners>

<test name="Test" parallel="none">
    <classes>                   
        <class name="Test case A"/>                     
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->

<test name="Test1" parallel="none">
    <classes>                   
        <class name="Test case B"/>                     
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Comment: Which version of extent are you using?